# crontab not working properly

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

When I run a script manually using root it is working fine. when I execute the same script inside cron it is not running. I checked the cron is actually calling the script but the script is not executing. I exported the output of echos in the script to the text file but the text file is didn't logged anything. Please check this cron

```
*/10 * * * *  sh /var/www/sym_monitor/restart.sh > /var/www/migrate/root_restart.txt
```

Comment: from which user crontab is running your script?

Comment: Add `2>&1` redirection to get `stderr` in your log file too.

Comment: @Anton I'm sorry Im a newbie. Where to add this 2>&1 in that script.

Comment: @pomaxa I'm running it under root cron in ubuntu server

Comment: Add it at the **end** of your command, **after** your redirection to `root_restart.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to avoid typing full executable paths is to put shell global variables at the top of your `crontab` :

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
MAIL=me@domain.tld

*/10 * * * * stuff > log 2>&1
```

Note the `> log 2>&1` syntax to log both `STDERR` & `STDOUT` in log file

Comment: i have same problem, when using curl it not work but /usr/bin/curl
it work perfect

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `sh` for `/bin/sh`.

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/sym_monitor/restart.sh > /var/www/migrate/root_restart.txt
```